# communicating with another computer using a crossover cable

Tags: networking, ssh, ping

I have two identical Dell E5580 laptops running Xenial.    I'm trying to pass data from one to another in an efficient way.    Both are on the same wireless subnet, but I figure a cross-over cable would be faster.    However, I've not been able to establish any communication using either the wifi network or the cross-over cable.   I've tried pinging one computer from another, ssh'ing and scp'ing but cannot make any kind of contact by any of these means between the two computers.    It makes no difference whether they are connected by cross-over cable or not.      Could somebody please suggest what I might try?   Thanks

As per @Buck_Crockett's request I'm reporting what happens when I ping one machine from another.    The first machine's IP is 192.168.1.210, the second's is 192.168.1.211.

When I ping the second from the first, I see:

```
PING 192.168.1.210 (192.168.1.210) 56(84) bytes of data
```

but nothing more.     When I ping the first from the second I see

```
PING 192.168.1.211 (192.168.1.211) 56(84) bytes of data
```

but nothing more.

Comment: There is a answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/786283/767056

Comment: Add the output of `ip a` and `route -n` from both machines, please.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/59906/how-do-i-connect-my-desktop-and-my-laptop-using-an-ethernet-cable-to-transfer-fi